# mongodb JDBC Driver class name and URL format

Tags: mongodb, jdbc, driver

anyone has JDBC Driver class name and URL format related to this mongodb driver mongo-java-driver-3.12.1.jar found here ?

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.12.1/

for 2 days i tried all what i found on the web and I get:

No suitable driver found for..

All what i found with clear information is here

http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php

which is not free

Comment: As far as I'm aware `org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver` is not a JDBC driver, so it doesn't have a JDBC `Driver` class name, nor a JDBC URL format. And asking for suggestions for alternatives is off topic.

Answer (score 0):

finally i used this one. it worked

https://bitbucket.org/dbschema/mongodb-jdbc-driver/src/master/

class: "com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver"
URL: "jdbc:mongodb://host:port"